# Memory exhausted using php://input

Tags: php, memory, input, upload, limit

When using fopen("php://input") to upload a 120MB file we get a "memory exhausted" warning from php. The php memory_limit is set to 256MB and we have enough memory available.

We removed all the code except for fopen("php://input") and it is still failing, so the error must be in there.

We tried different memory limits and at about 500MB the error disappears. Still, we really shouldn't use 500MB so the question remains: Why do we get a memory exhausted error using fopen on a file that's 115-120MB in size.

Our php test-file:

```
<?php
    $inputHandler = fopen('php://input', "r");
?>
```

And the error:

```
262144000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 120829495 bytes)
```

I hope someone can help us out. This is driving us mad!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't get that error on fopen() only when reading from $inputHandler

Comment: Your fopen handler isn't the only thing using your PHP memory. Use `memory_get_usage()` to see how much memory is already being used before you try to load the huge file into memory.

Comment: @MarkBaker That's what we also thought, but this is the only line of code and it is crashing on that. When we observe the httpd processes, we can see that the memory is rising when the file is being uploaded but it never get's above the 130MB.

Comment: @aynber every executing php script gets the memory_limit addressed. So the script I'm using should have 256MB to use

Comment: @MarkVisser I have this problem. can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure to unlimited memory usage:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: That's no option. We should not use more then 256MB

Answer (score 0):

It can be because php is trying to automatically parse POST data.
To disable this, in php version 5.4+ you can set enable_post_data_reading to 0. (I used .htaccess for this purpose)
But, actually, in php 5.4+ it is better to use $_FILES for uploads...